# .NET TextBox BackColor issue

Tags: .net, asp.net, textbox, backcolor

On a .NET page, I have a textbox. If I don't change the `BackColor` property, it looks flat. However, when using `BackColor`, e.g.:

```
txt.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
```

the look changes to some sort of "3D" which I don't really like. Is it possible to avoid this effect?

first:

[image]

edited:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems backcolor influences the borderstyle-property? which makes no sense to me,
but I can simulate the look of a "normal" textbox like this

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="valueTxt" Enabled="false" BackColor="#E8E8E8" Width="50px" BorderStyle="NotSet" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#B0B0B0"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of browsers. Browsers use the current OS and there own controls to render controls. So on a Mac using Safari, text boxes may look different to Firefox on Ubuntu & IE on Windows.

You can influence this by setting styles but you're still dependant on the browser. What would be better would be to create a css file with all the styles you want to apply to an input element defined, or create a css class so you can apply them independently. You only need reference the css file then to get the styling, rather than setting all those properties every time.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue where the text box was being set to ".Enabled=false" and ".BackColor = Color.LightGrey".  The textbox border was being changed to "3D".
Just setting the ".Enabled=false" sets the text box to grey by default.  Changing it back to ".Enabled=true" set the text box back to white.

The border was not changed.

So don't change the .BackColor if you do not have to.